# "Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person"?

Tags: java, variables, methods

For class I have to create a Java class definition to describe a car loan taken by two people. It has to contain:

1. bankName (a string)
2. accountNumber (an integer)
3. signer (a ***Person***)
4. coSigner (a ***Person***)

It also has to have a getInfo() method which concatenates bankName and accountNumber.

Below is my what I have for the car loan class in which I'm trying to create, but I also have to create another class file called Person.

**CarLoan.java:**

```
  package carloandemo.csc212hw01;

  public class CarLoan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bankName;
        bankName = "Chase";
        int accountNumber;
        accountNumber = 123456;
        Person signer;
        signer = "Rich";
        Person coSigner;
        coSigner = "Tim";
        String print = getInfo(bankName, accountNumber, signer, coSigner);
        System.out.println(print);
        //  System.out.println(getInfo() );
    }

    public static String getInfo(String bankName, int accountNumber, String signer, String coSigner) {
        return "The bank is " + bankName + " and the account number is " + accountNumber + ". " + "The signer of the loan is " + signer + " and the co-signer is " + coSigner + ".";

    }

  }
```

**Person.java:**

```
package carloandemo.csc212hw01;

public class Person {

   public String signer;
   public String coSigner;

}
```

For the code where I assign the Person variables signer and coSigner values, I am recieving an error that says "Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person". Because of this I am also receiving that error on the String print statement. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is the classes constructors ??

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it.

```
Person signer;
signer = "Rich";
```

You are defining signer as a `Person`, and you are assigning a `String` value.

First of all You have to init the `signer` to a `new Person()`, then you can assign the variable inside the new instance.

For example:

```
Person signer = new Person();
signer.signer = "Rich";
```

May be you can change your code in this way:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    //getter
}

public class CarLoan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bankName;
        bankName = "Chase";
        int accountNumber;
        accountNumber = 123456;

        Person signer = new Person("Rich" , "xxx");
        Person cosigner = new Person("Tim" , "xxx");

        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where the error message is telling you exactly what the problem is

> “Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Person”?

Your problem is here

```
Person signer;
signer = "Rich";
```

"Rich" is a string, not a person.

Create a new instance of Person and then assign "Rich" to the `signer` property of that instance.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.signer = "Rich";
```

Note though looking at this code:

```
Person coSigner;
coSigner = "Tim";
String print = getInfo(bankName, accountNumber, signer, coSigner);
```

you probably don't actually want the `Person` object to contain the `signer` and `coSigner` properties.  A better definition is probably

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    // Other things that describe a person here
}
```

If you change Person that way, your final code would be

```
Person signer = new Person();
signer.name = "Rich";
Person coSigner = new Person();
coSigner.name = "Tim";
String print = getInfo(bankName, accountNumber, signer, coSigner);
```